# select the min value between two rasters stacks

Tags: r, raster, min

I have two rasters: One represent the SIF value given the driest monthly VPD (vapor pressure deficit). The other one represent SIF values given the driest SM (soil moisture) month.  I want a final raster layer where each cell indicates the lowest value of SIF between the two rasters. However i need to know in the legend  whether the SIF value is related to VPD or SM.

> 

```
sif_min_vpd
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 255, 702, 179010  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -171, 180, -56, 71.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : SIF_deseasonalized 
values     : -3.453509, 2.578036  (min, max)
```

> 

```
sif_min_sm
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 255, 702, 179010  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -171, 180, -56, 71.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : SIF_deseasonalized 
values     : -1.728031, 2.55345  (min, max)
```

I tried this code:

```
final_map <- min(sif_min_vpd, sif_min_sm_aligned)
```

But then I can’t know if the SIF value either it’s VPD related or SM related.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check them without the min function?

```
if (sif_min_vpd < sif_min_sm_aligned) {
final_map <- c("vpd", sif_min_vpd)
}
else {
final_map <- c("sm", sif_min_sm_aligned)
}

print(final_map)
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in if (sif_min_vpd < sif_min_sm_aligned) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: What inside the class are you trying to get the min of? You will need to specify that in the if statement by accessing the class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc` along with `which.min`. It will show which layer contained the min value for each pixel, either layer 1 (vpd) or 2 (sm).

```
library(raster)
minlayer <- calc(stack(sif_min_vpd, sif_min_sm_aligned), which.min)
```

Comment: I get: Error in .local(x, values, ...) : 
  values must be numeric, integer or logical.